# Hello, how to make this program not count space as a letter and count uppercase and lowercase letters together as "one"

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to make this program not count space as a letter and count uppercase and lowercase letters together as "one"

```
word = str(input())
list = []
listchcounter = []

for character  in word:
    if character not in list:
        list.append(character)
        listchcounter.append(0)
for character in word:
    for index in range(len(list)):
        if list[index] == character:
            listchcounter[index] += 1
for index in range(len(list)):
    print("'" + list[index] + "'",'appears',listchcounter[index],'times')
```

Comment: `if character != ' '` and `character = character.lower()`. I also suggest you read this https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping instead of using lists

Comment: I have to make this through lists @Dimitry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only changes are in line 1 the .lower() behind the input. And in line 6 the and character != ' ' . Then the code already works fine.

```
word = str(input().lower())
list = []
listchcounter = []

for character  in word:
    if character not in list and character != ' ':
        list.append(character)
        listchcounter.append(0)
for character in word:
    for index in range(len(list)):
        if list[index] == character:
            listchcounter[index] += 1
for index in range(len(list)):
    print("'" + list[index] + "'",'appears',listchcounter[index],'times')
```

Answer (score 1):

The comments by @dimitry contain the basic ways to address your stated question.

To exclude spaces you want to filter them out with a `if character != ' '`.

To treat upper and lower cased letters as the same, you want to convert all characters to lowercase via `character = character.lower()`.

Let's put these together:

```
word = "foOtball Timeout"
letters = [letter.lower() for letter in word if letter != " "]
print(letters )
```

Giving us:

```
['f', 'o', 'o', 't', 'b', 'a', 'l', 'l', 't', 'i', 'm', 'e', 'o', 'u', 't']
```

Now we can count them. I would personally use `collections.Counter()` for this, but it is easy enough to do it by hand.

```
letter_counts = {}
for letter in letters:
    letter_counts[letter] = letter_counts.get(letter, 0) + 1
print(letter_counts )
```

Giving us the crux of what is required:

```
{'f': 1, 'o': 3, 't': 3, 'b': 1, 'a': 1, 'l': 2, 'i': 1, 'm': 1, 'e': 1, 'u': 1}
```

Now all that is left is to print the results out nicely:

```
for letter, count in letter_counts.items():
    print(f"The letter \"{letter}\" appears {count} time(s) in \"{word}\"")
```

Giving:

```
The letter "f" appears 1 time(s) in "foOtball Timeout"
The letter "o" appears 3 time(s) in "foOtball Timeout"
The letter "t" appears 3 time(s) in "foOtball Timeout"
The letter "b" appears 1 time(s) in "foOtball Timeout"
The letter "a" appears 1 time(s) in "foOtball Timeout"
The letter "l" appears 2 time(s) in "foOtball Timeout"
The letter "i" appears 1 time(s) in "foOtball Timeout"
The letter "m" appears 1 time(s) in "foOtball Timeout"
The letter "e" appears 1 time(s) in "foOtball Timeout"
The letter "u" appears 1 time(s) in "foOtball Timeout"
```

Full code:

```
word = "foOtball Timeout"
letter_counts = {}
for letter in [letter.lower() for letter in word if letter != " "]:
    letter_counts[letter] = letter_counts.get(letter, 0) + 1
for letter, count in letter_counts.items():
    print(f"The letter \"{letter}\" appears {count} time(s) in \"{word}\"")
```

or if you wanted to use `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections
word = "foOtball Timeout"
letter_counts = collections.Counter(l.lower() for l in word if l != " ")
for letter, count in letter_counts.items():
    print(f"The letter \"{letter}\" appears {count} time(s) in \"{word}\"")
```